# Example of uniform continuous unbounded function such $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \neq \infty$ or $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \neq -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I wanted to find Example of uniform continuous unbounded function such $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \neq \infty$ or  $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \neq -\infty$.But I did not get.I think there must be some function like oscillation with higher wavelenth as x goes large.Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like $f(x)=\sqrt x\sin\sqrt x$?
From $$f'(x)=\underbrace{\frac{\sin\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}}_{|\cdot|\le \frac12}+\underbrace{\frac{\cos\sqrt x}{2}}_{|\cdot|\le \frac12},$$ we see that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $1$, hence uniformly continuous.

---

Or (also as a function $[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$)$$f(x)=\min\{x-\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor^2-\tfrac12\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor ,\lceil\sqrt x\rceil^2-x-\tfrac12\lceil\sqrt x\rceil\}$$
Note that $f$ is the piecewise linear interpolation between the points $(k^2,-\frac12k)$ and $(k^2+k+\frac12,\frac12k+\frac12)$, hence again is Lipschitz with constant $1$, hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks, Sir. I was thinking to prove that this function is uct on R But Can not able to prove using the Continous extension, Bounded derivative or By definition.I s there is any other method to prove that?

Comment: Or is this due to the fact that $|\sqrt x \sin \sqrt x|$ <| x|